# Easyslider and drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, easyslider

I am currently trying to implement [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)  with my drupal instance.

I have managed to get it done for the most part . Pls visit my dev site at

http://www.iamvishal.com/dev/

If you click on the right arrow the  image slides but on the left you can see a bit of the image clipping.

I tried css but I can't seem to get rid of it. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Vishal

I managed to solve it.  The js is taking the overall width and height from the li components
So you need to change the css li details.

```
#slider2{margin-top:1em;}
#slider li, #slider2 li{ 
    /* 
        define width and height of list item (slide)
        entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
    */ 
    width:416px;
    height:287px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    }
```

Comment: To answer your own question make an answer and accept it. This way your question will be identified like an answered one.

Comment: mark it as accepted with the check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. The js is taking the overall width and height from the li components So you need to change the css li details.

```
#slider2{margin-top:1em;}
#slider li, #slider2 li{ 
/* 
    define width and height of list item (slide)
    entire slider area will adjust according to the parameters provided here
*/ 
width:416px;
height:287px;
overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

It's really amazing and easy to use.

Comment: I rather stick with easy slider